# ubuntu: 8GB machine... 7.6GB swap space

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've got Ubuntu 9.04 with 8GB and system monitor reports 2.6GB of Memory + 7.6GB of Swap.  What gives?

free -m

```
jldupont@jldupont-desktop:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2644       1621       1023          0         29        474
-/+ buffers/cache:       1116       1528 
Swap:         7742          0       7742
```

swapon -s

```
jldupont@jldupont-desktop:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                           partition   7928036 0   -1
```

uname -a

```
jldupont@jldupont-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux jldupont-desktop 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 20:50:00 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Dump of my dmesg output is available [here](http://pastebin.com/m489f7fe3).

Comment: Can you paste "free -m" output?

Comment: Oh and "swapon -s"

Comment: What does CMOS report for your memory? Could be bad RAM, or something wonky in the BIOS.

Comment: Glad it looks like you solved the issue. Memory issues can be a real @#% in the @#$ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems odd...  What does `top` or `free -m` from the command line report.  If you are running a 32-bit installation without the PAE (Physical Address Extension) kernel you would only see ~ 3.2 GB of physical memory. If that is the case install:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

to get the PAE kernel to use the full amount of memory.  You won't get more than 4 GB *per process*, but that probably doesn't matter. Alternatively, you could use the 64-bit version if it is a 64-bit machine.

Comment: ok, i have installed linux-server as directed: I still get 2.6G from top.  I am on a 32bit system. What's going on??

Comment: Did you reboot after installing that?

Comment: Did you also boot the server kernel? :)

Comment: As blank3 said, make sure you select that kernel in the Gurb boot menu, but I think it should default.  Grub will say something like press 'Something' for menu (ESC Maybe?), this will let you select the kernel.  With Linux, you generally don't have to reboot after any updates, except the kernel.  Sometimes rebooting makes it easier though.  It is possible to update the kernel without rebooting, but that is kind of new territory: www.ksplice.com

Comment: Yes I have selected the -server kernel and still System Monitor reports 2.6G Memory available or more precisely:  1.0GB of 2.6GB used.

Comment: And the BIOS at boot sees all 8 GB? Might need to enable a more verbose boot in the BIOS settings, but can probably see what the memory is in there somewhere too.  If the BIOS can't see the memory, maybe your memory isn't seated properly, you need to update the bios, or you are not using compatible memory.

Comment: @Kyle: yes the BIOS reports 8GB.

Comment: Alright, maybe look through the output of the `dmesg` command and see if that says anything helpful... Also verify your current running kernel with `uname -a`

Comment: And you are not using xen or anything like that right? or the mem boot paramter to the kernel ( maybe post output of `cat /boot/grub/menu.lst` )

Comment: @Kyle: I've updated the question with output from "uname -a". Secondly, I am not using xen (no mention of it in menu.lst).

Comment: I've done a pastebin of my dmesg: http://pastebin.com/m489f7fe3

Comment: And there is no mem= is the menu.lst?

Comment: @kyle: pastebin of menu.lst : http://pastebin.com/d264fc720

Comment: Well, looking at the Physical RAM map, looks like the BIOS tells the kernel that you have about 2.7 usable (You can convert the hex to decimal in the shell: `echo $((0xa7f80000))` ).  At this point I might look into updating the BIOS, or be patient as see what idea anyone else might have. Sorry I don't have the answer :-/

Comment: You might also try submitting a bug for ubuntu's launchpad with all this info.

Comment: ... I might have mixed up memory types when I built the machine... I'll have a look into this before bothering more folks!  Thanks to all!!!

Comment: 8GB and 32bit is going to waste at least half your memory.

Comment: David, even with PAE?

Comment: @david: you are right: when I put together this machine, I just used the memory handy and I believe now (thanks to all!!) that I might have mixed memory types that Linux doesn't appreciate...

Answer (score 1):

Check what memory is reported in the CMOS configuration - maybe you have faulty hardware.

Assuming you have a 32-bit CPU, the system monitor should report 4.0 GiB memory. Try removing the excess 4GB. On the other hand, if you have a 64 bit CPU, then install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

During installation on a new hard drive the swap partition normally defaults to the same size as the memory, so the 8GB seems normal. Although, in practice, the more memory that there is available the less likely you are to require swap space.

Comment: System Monitory reports 1GB out of 2.6GB total available.

Answer (score 0):

running the 32 bit version of Ubuntu? It won't see past 4 gig of memory unless running the 64 bit version.

Running "file /sbin/init" on the terminal should give a hint of what bitness you're running.

Comment: How big is your actual swap partition? Try running gparted and it'll show you your partitions graphically and show you the physical partitions available. After that you can determine what is happening with the swap physical vs. RAM.

Comment: sounds like you're getting a combination of physical swap + memory being utilized.

Comment: -1 , 32 bit PAE kernels can see past 4GB. PAE (on most versions of Ubuntu) is supported by default.

Comment: @tinkertim - afaik it's only enabled on server kernels no desktop editions.

Comment: @tinkertim - I thought it was only on servers by default. Second, he's got 8 gig of RAM, sees 2.6 + 7.6 swap. That comes to 10.2 if I'm doing the math right. Usually you hit a limit in the 4 gig range if it's related to bit-ness. So the first thing I suspect is RAM+Swap+kernel misconfiguration. If someone else has speculation of what to look at first, chime in...still doesn't hurt to check the math of his swap partition + memory to see what he gets.